# Google Static Maps API dynamic links with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, google-maps-static-api

Is there a way to make Google Static Maps API links dynamic inside a pug(jade) template?

For example,

```
img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=52.241770, -0.900181&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=true&markers=52.241770, -0.900181&scale=2&key=API_KEY')
```

works but

```
img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={location.coords.lng},{location.coords.lat}&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=true&markers={location.coords.lng},{location.coords.lat}&scale=2&key=API_KEY')
```

does not.

Answer (score 1):

What about using quotes ?

```
img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="  + location.coords.lng + "," + location.coords.lat + "&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=true&markers=" + location.coords.lng + "," + location.coords.lat + "&scale=2&key=API_KEY")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
img.img-responsive.img-rounded(src=`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${location.coords.lng},${location.coords.lat}&zoom=17&size=400x350&sensor=true&markers=${location.coords.lng},${location.coords.lat}&scale=2&key=API_KEY`)
```